# How to get the value from ArrayList<Object> in android

Tags: android

i have created a getter and setter class as follow:

public class LayoutClass {

```
private boolean layoutstatus;

    public void setlayoutStatus(boolean layoutstatus)
    {
        this.layoutstatus=layoutstatus;
    }
    public boolean getlayoutStatus()
    {
        return this.layoutstatus;
    }

    public void setlayoutstring(String layoutstring)
    {
        this.layoutstring=layoutstring;
    }
    public String getlayoutstring()
    {
        return this.layoutstring;
    }
}
```

and a class for store data in arraylist as given below:

```
public class LayoutListClass {
     public static final ArrayList<LayoutClass> layoutList = new ArrayList<LayoutClass>();

}
```

i have added the value in a activity as folow:

```
LayoutClass layoutobj=new LayoutClass();
layoutobj.setlayoutstring("test1");
layoutobj.setlayoutStatus(true);
LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj);      

layoutobj.setlayoutstring("test2");
layoutobj.setlayoutStatus(true);
LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj);


layoutobj.setlayoutstring("test3");
layoutobj.setlayoutStatus(false);
LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj);
```

and when i am going to get the value:

```
for(LayoutClass layoutobj:LayoutListClass.layoutList)
            {
                Log.i("Layout "+g,"->"+layoutobj.getlayoutstring()+" Status = "+layoutobj.getlayoutStatus());

            }
```

i am only able to getting the last value "test3" all three times.

i want to know how to get the proper value or how to store the object of arraylist and used it later.

Comment: The way you are adding the object is wrong. You have created the single object and you are just overwriting the values. Create multiple objects and then add it to your list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LayoutClass layoutobj=new LayoutClass();
layoutobj.setlayoutstring("test");
layoutobj.setlayoutStatus(true);

LayoutClass layoutobj1=new LayoutClass();
layoutobj1.setlayoutstring("test1");
layoutobj1.setlayoutStatus(true);

LayoutClass layoutobj2=new LayoutClass();
layoutobj2.setlayoutstring("test2");
layoutobj2.setlayoutStatus(false);

LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj);
LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj1);
LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj2);
```

Do it like this.

Why you are getting the last value, because you are changing the value of a single object  you need to create object for every position in  Arraylist

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem in adding objects to `ArrayList` in this code:

```
LayoutClass layoutobj=new LayoutClass();
layoutobj.setlayoutstring("test1");
layoutobj.setlayoutStatus(true);
LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj);      

layoutobj.setlayoutstring("test2");
layoutobj.setlayoutStatus(true);
LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj);


layoutobj.setlayoutstring("test3");
layoutobj.setlayoutStatus(false);
LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj);
```

you add the same object every time.
you need to initiate new object before adding.

try something like this

```
LayoutClass layoutobj=new LayoutClass();
layoutobj.setlayoutstring("test1");
layoutobj.setlayoutStatus(true);
LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj);      

LayoutClass layoutobj1=new LayoutClass();
layoutobj1.setlayoutstring("test2");
layoutobj1.setlayoutStatus(true);
LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj1);

LayoutClass layoutobj2=new LayoutClass();
layoutobj2.setlayoutstring("test3");
layoutobj2.setlayoutStatus(false);
LayoutListClass.layoutList.add(layoutobj2);
```